# Visual Studio 2017 not recognizing "system"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017.  When I opened a program that I had written in 2015, system and tolower were flagged as undefined and I could not get the code to compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#include "CashRegister.h"
#include "Inventory.h"
#include "CustomerDB.h"
#include "Customer.h"
#include "Report.h"
#include "InventoryBook.h"

const string INVENTORY_FILENAME = "inventory.dat";

void cashRegisterMenu(CashRegister& cr, Inventory& inv);
void customerMenu(CustomerDB& cdb);
void inventoryMenu(Inventory& inv);
void reportMenu(Report& rep, Inventory& inv, CustomerDB& cdb);
void displayBookInfo(const InventoryBook* book);
void displayCustomerInfo(Customer customer);
InventoryBook makeBook();
InventoryBook editBook(const InventoryBook* book);
Customer makeCustomer();

int main()
{
    char choice;
    //float cost;
    CashRegister cr;
    Inventory inv(INVENTORY_FILENAME);
    Report rep;
    CustomerDB cdb;

    do
    {
        system("CLS");  // UNDEFINED
        cout << "Welcome to the Serendipity Booksellers POS Software System"
            << endl << endl;
        cout << "Options:" << endl << endl;
        cout << "R - Cash Register" << endl;
        cout << "I - Inventory" << endl;
        cout << "C - Customer" << endl;
        cout << "H - Report" << endl;
        cout << "Q - Quit Program" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Enter option: ";

        choice = tolower(cin.get()); // UNDEFINED
```

I ended up creating a new project and moving all the files into the new project. When I did this, everything worked in the new project but all the code is exactly the same. I really do not want to have to do this for every program I had written in some version of VS prior to 2017. Any one have any ideas of what might have happened and how I could have corrected it without creating a new project and copying the files over?

Comment: Trim `main` to it has only `system("CLS");` and then build. If it still has problems, trim all the header files except `#include <cstdlib>`. If it still has a problem, that will be great [mcve] to post. If it does not have a problem with that, you can keep adding stuff until it has a problem. Then, you can post that.

Comment: Simple answer, don't use `system()` - there iis almost never a good reason to do so, and it inevitably makes your code non-portable.

Comment: Regardless of what the reason for your problem is, I applaud VS2017 for giving you cause to rethink your use of `system()`. It should *not* be used. Bad function; no cookie for you.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth not to mention all the potential security headaches...

Comment: Are you saying the IDE flagged them as undefined (like with a red squiggle) or did the compiler or linker give a build-time error?  If the latter, please include the complete text of the error message(s).

Comment: Yes the IDE flagged them as undefined (with a red squiggle). And for all those who are saying not to use system, that doesn't really answer the question. As you might have notice it is also marking tolower() as undefined, should I not use that as well. Also, you might want to stop applauding because VS2017 still lets you use system() as I said in my original post, I was able to copy the code into a new project and it all worked. I am just trying to figure what might be causing it not to work in the original project.